# deleting a line from a txt file doesnt work

Tags: c++

I want to delete a line in my txt file which is

```
student courses
s111 cs214
s222 cs112
s333 cs218
```

And i want to remove line 2 from it which is s222 cs112 and i have tried to use this code of getline but instead of deleting one line..it keeps the line that the user inputs and deletes the rest[note:user enters an input which is matched if it is equal to that array it executes ] ...This is my code of deleting line of text

```
string course;
string stud;
int i = 0;
cout << "PLease enter course to delete" << endl;
cin >> stud;
while (stud != registration_details[i].get_id()) {
    fstream ofs;
    ofs.open("Registration.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    ofs << registration_details[i].get_id() << registration_details[i].get_course();
    ofs.close();
    i++;
}
```

but after i enter cs222 in inputs[stud] this is what happens to my file..

```
student courses
s111 cs214
```

the input which i want it to be deleted deletes but along with it, it deletes the third section also which was s333
please help

Comment: You just need to open the file before the while loop and close it after the same. What you're doing is opening and truncating the file for each record!

Comment: The while loop exits when the condition is false and last lines will not get printed

Comment: check the condition in the while loop. 
hint: as per condition in while loop, whenever the line which is to be deleted is found, fstream will get the line to be printed and then stream closes. 
**what about the lines in text file which are after the line you intend to delete.**

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your loop does.  It loops over the `registration_details` array until it finds the element to delete.  Within the loop, it removes the file and replaces it with a single line file containing the current element of the array.  So unless you tell it to remove the first line (in which case it will do nothing), it will replace the file with a single line containing just the line before the one you asked to delete.

You need to open the file ONCE (before the loop), and then loop over ALL the elements in array (so don't stop when you find the line to delete).  For each entry that is NOT the entry to delete you need to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop which we use will exit when the condition is false. That is in your case when the match is found. So the Application will not print the next set of lines after that.
What you could do is:

- Loop Over all the Lines
- Add `if` Condition and `continue` the line
  which make the match

Refer sample code below

```
fstream ofs;
ofs.open("Registration.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
for ( const auto& oLineDetails : registration_details )
{
    if ( stud == oLineDetails.get_id() )
    {
        continue;
    }
    ofs << oLineDetails.get_id() << oLineDetails.get_course();
}
ofs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:
1. the while condition, which will exit when false (i.e. when stud is a match)
2. opening and truncating the file for each record

What is registration_details? Is it a vector or array? I would get its size first either using the `size()` of std::vector or `sizeof(registration_details) / sizeof(registration_details[0])` for a C-style array and store it in a variable size. Then I would do the following:

```
fstream ofs;
ofs.open("Registration.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);

for (size_t i=0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if (stud != registration_details[i].get_id())
    {
        ofs << registration_details[i].get_id() << " " << registration_details[i].get_course() << std::endl;
    }
}

ofs.close();
```

Comment: thank you BUT upon running the program i inputted "s111" as stud and also got the right input but my txt file has combined both students and courses like as for             "s222 cs112" it has combined and and its shows "S222cs112" without a space in txt file..any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Anuraag See the updated code. This will insert a space between id and course, as well as a new line at the end for each record.